# Java reflection: Get inner instantiated field

Tags: java, reflection, inner-classes

I have an interface which looks like this:

```
public interface A {
    public interface B {
        public static final Cat cat = new Cat("Alice");
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can access the Cat object through reflection?

I have tried this:

```
Field catField = Class.forName("A.B").getField("cat");
```

But it gives me a ClassNotFoundException.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for this is:

```
Field catField = Class.forName("com.xx.A$B").getField("cat");
System.out.println(catField.toString());
```

(I can't tell if your package declaration is missing or not, if it is then it needs to be added)

Comment: Thanks! Accepting this because you were first :)

Comment: You're welcome, the other answer came before mine though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Outer$Inner` syntax with reflection, not `Outer.Inner`.

Answer (score 0):

You shall use `InterfaceName.class`.

```
    Class cat;
    try {
        cat = A.B.class;
        Field catField = cat.getField("cat");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```